# Spring boot and async + database transaction

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, asynchronous, download

I encountered on following problem in `spring boot` application with `rest api`.

The problem is that when an user calls rest api to download csv file then the processing of file is executed in async process - `downloadFile`.

I would like to inform users about state of async process via next rest api end point - `getState`.

But here is the root of issue. There on `downloadFile` is used repository to saveAndFlush the information about progress into database table - TableStatus. However when calling `getState` then it doesnt see such row in database table TableStatus.

**- Please what can be wrong and how we can manage it?** Thanks

I know that it is probably caused by transaction that was not yet commited. I found out that transaction for `downloadFile` is commited after end of async process.

Some short code summary for better image:

```
Endpoint 1)
@Async
void downloadFile() {
    //processing file
    while (true) {
       putInfoAboutState(50);

    }
}

@Transactional
void putInfoAboutState(e) {
    repo.saveAndFlush(e);
}


Endpoint 2)
Integer getState(i) {
    return repo.getByOne(i);
}
```